# JSON POST request returns response in HTML not JSON

Tags: python, json, post, web-scraping, request

I am trying to scrape a website with a DOM so I thought the best way to go about it would be to send a post request to the server through requests and then receive the JSON response. I am able to see the response received in Chrome's Inspect Element tool but not in python.
This is my code, I am getting the HTML response which is the whole page but not the JSON response which is the data I am after.

```
import requests
import json
url="https://www.umass.edu/peoplefinder/"

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
searchData={'q': 'Alex'}
response=requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(searchData), headers=headers)
content = response.json()    
print(content)
```

I am able to get the data in the Chrome responses tab something like this.

```
{
    "ErrorHint": "",
    "ErrorCode": 0,
    "OverflowFlag": true,
    "Results": [{
    "Affil": ["Employee"],
    "Vcard": "/peoplefinder/vcard/xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Title": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Phone": ["xxxxxxx"],
    "Dept": ["xxxxxxxxxxx"],
    "Building": ["xxxxxxxxxx"],
    "Email": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Name": "xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this inside python?

Comment: import json, see examples of json.loads () and json.load() unless response is already in proper format. If it is, e.g. affil_0 = response["Results"][0][""Affil"] might help. affil_0 woluld be a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this.

```
import requests
url="https://www.umass.edu/peoplefinder/engine/"

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
payload = {'q': 'Alex'}

s = requests.session()
response = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally got it to work.
This Answer is correct along with the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should fetch you the desired response.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.umass.edu/peoplefinder/engine/"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response = requests.post(url, data={'q': 'Alex'}, headers=headers) 
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally got it to work.
This Answer is correct along with the other answer.